# How to read all files with wild card formatting in c#

Tags: c#

So normally, I would have a file path like `out/path/` and I would use `Directory.GetFiles(path)` to get all files in that path.  Now, if my input is `out/path/*.csv` how would I go about grabbing all files meeting that parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by grabbing all files? What operations are you try to perform on those files?

Comment: Just use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. It lets you define a search pattern.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles("out/path", "*.csv");

Comment: Thanks @taquion that solved it.

Comment: @jasodjas someone has provided the solution as answer, you should mark this question as answered.

Comment: @taquion Yep, I did.  I was just away in some meetings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Directory.GetFiles(String, String) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_):

```
Directory.GetFiles("out/path", "*.csv");
```